# How do I write a function to escape all double quotes in a string in Python?

Tags: python

How can I replace all the `"` with the raw string `\"` in a string such as `"Hello", said he.` in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
s = '"Hello", said he.'
print s.replace('"', r'\"')

# output
\"Hello\", said he.
```

It helps to use the `r''` notation to indicate that the string should be raw and not interpreted. Helps with backslashes.

Answer (score 3):

Use `replace()`.

```
>>> print '"Hello"'.replace('"', '\\"')
\"Hello\"
```